# Amazon AWS EC2 Key Pair Denied

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have scoured the Internet for answers and had little luck. All I have been trying to do is connect to my AWS EC2 Linux server via SSH.

The.pem file is on my computer, but it has not been accepted. I have tried several FTP clients, including FileZilla and the native Terminal on my Mac.

In FileZilla, my error is the following:

> Error:Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

I also have encountered a similar message in Terminal:

> Warning: Identity file rejectedFile.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
>   Permission denied (publickey).

I have quadruple-checked the file name corresponds to the one in the AWS console. This file was downloaded when I initialized the instance...

Comment: what are the permissions on the key? can you share the ssh command you are using and the output? I would do ssh -vvv <put your other params in here>

Comment: also, from the limited info you've shared so far seems that there is a problem with the key as it's not picked up by whatever programing you are attempting to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you check also these two common mistakes:

- Wrong permissions of the .pem file: make sure the file exists with proper permissions (chmod 400)
- Default username: use the proper username for your linux distro

> Use the ssh command to connect to the instance. You'll specify the
>   private key (.pem) file and user_name@public_dns_name. For Amazon
>   Linux, the user name is ec2-user. For RHEL5, the user name is either
>   root or ec2-user. For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu. For Fedora, the
>   user name is either fedora or ec2-user. For SUSE Linux, the user name
>   is root. Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with your
>   AMI provider.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: Thank you. Permissions on the .pem file was definitely the issue. Now on to installing LAMP...